# Is "ahead" enough or should it be "ahead of me"?

Tags: grammar

I was distracted for a second, so I didn't see the deer step out onto the road ahead (of me).

Do I need to add "of me" here or is "ahead" enough?

Answer (score 2):

It's fine either way.

With "of me" my sense is that the deer is closer to you than just plain "ahead" suggests. The latter could be farther off down the road.

Comment: What about "up ahead"? Would that suggest that the deer was closer to me than using "ahead" or would it be the same?

Comment: I think "up ahead"  suggests somewhat closer than "ahead" but further away than "ahead of me". But the difference is slight. What's best depends on the full context surrounding the sentence.